# parse html inside ng-bind using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-parsing

I'm having issue with angularJs. My application requests some data from the server and one of the values from the data returned from the server is a string of html. I am binding it in my angular template like this

```
<div>{{{item.location_icons}}</div>
```

but as you might expect what I see is not the icons images but the markup 
basically the stuff in the div looks like

```
 "<i class='my-icon-class'/>"
```

which is not what I want.

anyone know what I can do to parse the html in the transclusion

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You want to use `ng-bind-html` and `ng-bind-html-unsafe` for that kind of purpose.

The examples are shown [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize#examples)

Comment: how would I use this with ng-bind-html I see how I can use ng-bind-unsafe-html not sure if unsafe is a way of suggesting that it is a bad way of doing things. Can you elaborate on the ng-bind-html? The angular docs aren't very clear on this. I tried using it and it didn't work

Comment: Honestly, I do not know exactly.  But my understanding is that sanitizer will remove tags with any external references, such as `href`, `src`, etc...  If you are binding user input, then it can be unsafe, but you are binding to your own internal value, I think it is OK to use un-sanitized version.

Comment: `ng-bind-html` is in the `ngSanitize` module, which, like `ngResource` isn't prepackaged with Angular. You'll have to include the script and make sure your app depends on it: `var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']);`. You'll then have access to the `ng-bind-html` directive, which you can use like: `<div ng-bind-html="somemodel"></div>`

Comment: thank you both for the answers they have been very helpful

Comment: @EdgarMartinez "unsafe" in this context means the source of the data is not trusted (e.g. the html came from user input via a form)

Comment: You can find all the plugins here: http://code.angularjs.org/

Comment: Use `ng-bind-html` together with the `$sanitize` provider

Answer (score 18):

As ng-bind-html-unsafe is deprecated, you can use this code instead.

You need to create function inside your controller:

```
$scope.toTrustedHTML = function( html ){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml( html );
}
```

and use something like this in your view:

```
<span ng-bind-html='toTrustedHTML( myHTMLstring )'></span>
```

Don't forget to inject $sce:

```
AppObj.controller('MyController', function($scope, $sce) {
    //your code here 
});
```

Answer (score 8):

A better way is to use `$compile` instead of `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.

See: [http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile)

Lastly, at the moment, the last version of angularJS (release candidate 1.2.0) do not have any `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive. So I really encourage you to consider this option before any future update of your app. ( `ng-bind-html-unsafe` may/will not working any more...)

[http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0rc1/docs/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtml)

Comment: Don't you mean [$sanitize](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.$sanitize) rather than $compile?