# How to parse HTML in ng-repeat in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, html-parsing, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to parse optional HTML from my model in ng-repeat.

I have a repeater in a .jade template like this:

```
tr(ng-repeat='car in cars')
  td(class='arrived-{{car.arrived}}') {{car.number}}
  td(class='arrived-{{car.arrived}}') {{car.location}}
```

my **car.location** can be plain text like:

`City name`

or it can have some html in it, like this:

```
In transit,  <a href="http://example.com/"/>view</a>
```

Now, when I get the HTML, this doesn't get parsed. The data is unfortunately from a third party site, so I can't influence that. Is there a directive or filter that could turn this into a valid link?

If not, what else could I try to do with it?

Comment: Thanks for marking it duplicate, @georgeawg. Out of curiosity - how do you decide which question is a duplicate of what? E.g. this one is from 2013, the linked answer is from 2016, so it's clearly not by age.

Comment: The answer here is obsolete and no longer works. The `ng-bind-html-unsafe` directive was removed from AngularJS for security reasons.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you need is `ng-bind-html-unsafe`.
It parses the HTML correctly ;)

Example: http://jsbin.com/ubujem/1/

`<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="car.location"></p>`

Also this question seems similarly to this: [parse html inside ng-bind using angularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888822/parse-html-inside-ng-bind-using-angularjs)

Comment: Do you have an example of applying this to a jade template?

Comment: For jade it should be something like p(ng-bind-html-unsafe="{{car.location}}"), not?