# Printing HTML in ng-repeat

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an ngController which contains, amongst other things, an array of questions and answers:

```
$scope.faqs = [
        {
            question: "QUESTION 1",
            answer: "ANSWER 1"
        },
        {
            question: "What is the dress code?",    
            answer: "See <a href=\"https://www.brides.com/story/wedding-dress-code-explained\">here</a>."
        },
        {
            question: "QUESTION 3",
            answer: "ANSWER 3"
        }
    ];
```

In my HTML I then cycle through these to display them:

```
<div> 
    <div ng-controller="FAQController" class="FAQ_container">
        <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
            <button class="collapsible">{{ faq.question }}</button>
            <div class="content">
                <p>{{ faq.answer }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

However, for the middle question in my array, it prints the whole item as a string. I can understand why this is the case, however I would like for it to have the link clickable.

I have tried the suggestion from [How to parse HTML in ng-repeat in angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712350/how-to-parse-html-in-ng-repeat-in-angular-js) by changing my

```
<p>{{ faq.answer }}</p>
```

to

```
<p ng-bind-html-unsafe="faq.answer"></p>
```

but that has just served to stop anything printing. Can anyone help with an alternative suggestion or fix please?

---

Please note: I am just starting out with angularjs and web development so please  try to keep your answers simple and bear with me if I have to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ngSanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) and make your `answer`s to be trusted has html like this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.faqs, function(faq) {
  faq.answer = $sce.trustAsHtml(faq.answer);
});
```

For this you will need to use the [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service.

And then bind them like this: `<p ng-bind-html="faq.answer"></p>`

See below **working** full sample:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize']).controller('FAQController', function($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.faqs = [{
      question: "QUESTION 1",
      answer: "ANSWER 1"
    },
    {
      question: "What is the dress code?",
      answer: "See <a href=\"https://www.brides.com/story/wedding-dress-code-explained\">here</a>."
    },
    {
      question: "QUESTION 3",
      answer: "ANSWER 3"
    }
  ];
  angular.forEach($scope.faqs, function(faq) {
    faq.answer = $sce.trustAsHtml(faq.answer);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.14/angular-sanitize.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="FAQController" class="FAQ_container">
    <div ng-repeat="faq in faqs">
      <button class="collapsible">{{ faq.question }}</button>
      <div class="content">
        <p ng-bind-html="faq.answer"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I had read about this a bit but hadn't managed to get it working!