# returning formatted String via AngularJS {{ }}

Tags: angularjs, fonts, angularjs-directive

I am trying to get a formatted String through a function, through an AngularJS {{ curly brackets }} in the HTML.

In the HTML, you have:

```
<center> {{italicsPlease()}} </center>
```

And in your AngularJS Javascript, you have this method:

```
$scope.italicsPlease = function() {
    return "I am Italicised".italics();
}
```

What you get in the HTML, is literally...

```
<i>I am Italicised</i>
```

It is not formatted in italics, but the string actually includes the  tags.

How do you get it so that you actually get a formatted string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse html inside ng-bind using angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888822/parse-html-inside-ng-bind-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works,

```
<center ng-bind-html-unsafe="italicsPlease()"></center>
```

Thank you for your answers. 
Thank you Stewie for your reference (my question searching skills are lacking).