# AngularJS: html special characters are not showing

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to display a string in my model that contains the html representation of a special character. Unfortunately, it doesn't show that actual character, and I don't know how to make  it do it...

this is the code:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{namea}}!
    <br/>
    &lt;
</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.namea = 'Superhero &lt;';
}
</script>
```

this is the output:

```
Hello, Superhero &lt;! 
<
```

[here is a jsfiddle for that](http://jsfiddle.net/7HhPF/1/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [parse html inside ng-bind using angularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888822/parse-html-inside-ng-bind-using-angularjs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [ng-bind-html-unsafe directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angBindHtmlUnsafe):

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-bind-html-unsafe="'Hello,' + namea">
</div>
```

Check out the [examples in the docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize.%24sanitize) and the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7HhPF/7/).

Comment: With newer version of angular, ng-bind-html-unsafe doesn't exists anymore. You will need to use ng-bind-html in your html template and $sce.trustAsHtml('Superhero &lt;) in the js function

Answer (score 19):

I ran into this problem today. Using AngularJS, in data inside a controller, I was trying to include a string with 'n' with tilde. I tried "Español" as well as the html representation, and neither displayed the desired output.

A coworker helpfully pointed out that unicode works. So I tried

```
{
name : "my site en Espan\u00F1ol"
}
```

which gave me

```
my site en Español
```

as desired. Check out http://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: I'm new to angular, but what I don't get is that if it's on a page that's already in utf8 encoding, why is the html encoding even happening?  ñ is a legal character in that environment and even latin 1; it's not an html syntax character like &, <, or >.  It's not even "dicey" like ' or ".  So why is angular mucking with it and is there a way to make it stop?

Comment: This is by far the better answer. Thank you so much.